# Google Sheets query() "Unable to parse query string" ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet where in Column B I have a product name and column D I have the total order value for that product.
And then every row is the individual order.

I've been trying to use query so I can get an output of:

Product 1: X total order value
Product 2: X total order value
Product 3: X total order value

I have called the table I'm pulling the data from EFW and it covers columns `A:I`

The query I have used is:

```
=query(EFW,"SELECT B,D, COUNT(D) GROUP BY D")
```

It gives me a parse error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: B

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have to add B to GROUP BY:

```
=query(EFW,"SELECT B,D, COUNT(D) GROUP BY B, D")
```